# load files from external modules without export

Tags: node.js

How to link another file from another module like that: 
`require('module2/file2_in_module2.js')`

I created module `module2` with 2 files: `index.js` and `file2_in_module2.js`. Run `npm link`. And in another module named `module1` I try to link `module2`. Run `npm link module2`. Ok.

Now in `module1` I get access to `index.js` from `module2`:

`var indexFromModule2 = require('module2')`
It's ok.

Now in `module1` I want to get access to file `file2_in_module2.js`. How to do it?

I **tried**: `require('module2/file2_in_module2.js')`. But it **fails**.

I know, that I **can** get access to it if I write:

`exports.File2 = require('./file2_in_module2.js')` in `index.js` of `module2` and get it in `module 1`:

`var file2 = require('module2').File2`

But I want to avoid this extra code:
`exports.File2 = require './file2_in_module2.js'`

Comment: `require('module2/file2_in_module2.js')` works for normal modules, there might be some special case for linked modules...

Comment: Just tried with a linked module and it still works. In what way does it fail?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module `module2/file2_in_module2.js`

Comment: I created new clear project with this example and it really works. Thanx to Andreas.

Comment: The error was because of typo in path: require('module2/file_TYPO_2_in_module2.js')

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do this, and you need to export all required components from your main module file.